# Как найти разность времени на языке Си?

Tags: время, c

Формировал время t1,t2 по mktime. Теперь надо найти разность. У меня почему то часы на 6 часов больше. Что делать?

Comment: Приведите код формирования времени и нахождения разницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверь часовые пояса. Возможно у тебя время формируется по GMT

Comment: А как вообще установить часовой пояс?

Comment: @Drakon, установка текущей timezone в системе может различаться в разных версиях \*nix, но часто (для linux) сводится к установке нужного /etc/localtime, для пользователя можно менять environment переменную TZ, вообще для конкретного запуска программы почитайте `man tzset`, там много всего написано...

Answer (score 4):

Наверное, когда Вы посчитали разность в секундах `tm_sec_diff = (mktime(&tm1) - mktime(&tm2))`, то потом считаете разность в годах, днях, часах и т.д., вызывая `localtime(tm_sec_diff)`, а надо вызывать `gmtime(tm_sec_diff)`.

Собственно, самому стало интересно и набросал программку. Вроде работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  tzset();
  struct tm tm1, tm2;
  time_t now = time(0), loc, utc;

  printf ("now: %s\n", ctime(&now));
  tm1 = *gmtime(&now);
  printf ("now: %d:%d:%d %d of %d\n",
      tm1.tm_hour, tm1.tm_min, tm1.tm_sec,   
      tm1.tm_yday, tm1.tm_year + 1900);
  tm2 = *localtime(&now);
  printf ("local now: %d:%d:%d %d of %d\n",
      tm2.tm_hour, tm2.tm_min, tm2.tm_sec,   
      tm2.tm_yday, tm2.tm_year + 1900);

  utc = mktime(&tm2);
  loc = mktime(&tm1);

  time_t diff = abs(loc - utc);
  printf ("local - utc diff (sec): %ld\n", (long)diff);
  tm1 = *gmtime(&diff);
  printf ("utc diff: %d:%d:%d %d of %d\n",
      tm1.tm_hour, tm1.tm_min, tm1.tm_sec,   
      tm1.tm_yday, tm1.tm_year);
  tm2 = *localtime(&diff);
  printf ("local diff: %d:%d:%d %d of %d\n",
      tm2.tm_hour, tm2.tm_min, tm2.tm_sec,   
      tm2.tm_yday, tm2.tm_year);

  char buf[1024];

  while (fputs("Enter YYYY Month(1-12) DD(1-31) hh mm : ", stdout),
     fflush(stdout),
     fgets(buf, 1024, stdin)) {
    int year = 0, mnth = 0, mday = 0, hh = 0, mm = 0;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d %d %d", &year, &mnth, &mday, &hh, &mm) < 3) {
      puts("no data");
      continue;
    }
    char t[256];
    t[0] = 0;
    if (year < 0)
      strcat(t, "year ");
    if (mnth < 1 || mnth > 12)
      strcat(t, "month ");
    if (mday < 1 || mday > 31)
      strcat(t, "day ");
    if (hh < 0 || hh > 23)
      strcat(t, "hours ");
    if (mm < 0 || mm > 59)
      strcat(t, "munutes");
    if (t[0]) {
      printf ("bad value of: %s\n", t);
      continue;
    }
    struct tm tm,  tmd;
    tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_min = mm;
    tm.tm_hour = hh;
    tm.tm_mday = mday;
    tm.tm_mon = mnth - 1;
    tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;

    time_t diff, now = time(0), 
      tim = mktime(&tm); // local time in tm.tm_... !!!
    if (tim == -1L) {
      puts("Can't convert to seconds since Epoch");
      continue;
    }
    diff = labs(now - tim);
    tmd = *gmtime(&diff); // GMT !!!
    printf ("diff: %ld (sec)   %d:%d:%d (h:m:s) %d (days of) %d years\n",
        (long)diff,
        tmd.tm_hour, tmd.tm_min, tmd.tm_sec,   
        tmd.tm_yday, tmd.tm_year - 70);
  }

  return 0;
}

avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc timediff.c 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
now: Thu Aug  8 16:16:30 2013

now: 12:16:30 219 of 2013
local now: 16:16:30 219 of 2013
local - utc diff (sec): 14400
utc diff: 4:0:0 0 of 70
local diff: 7:0:0 0 of 70
Enter YYYY Month(1-12) DD(1-31) hh mm : 2013 8 8 17 17
diff: 3594 (sec)   0:59:54 (h:m:s) 0 (days of) 0 years
Enter YYYY Month(1-12) DD(1-31) hh mm : 1959 21 1 11
bad value of: month 
Enter YYYY Month(1-12) DD(1-31) hh mm : 1959 1 21 11
diff: 1721362665 (sec)   4:17:45 (h:m:s) 200 (days of) 54 years
Enter YYYY Month(1-12) DD(1-31) hh mm : avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Подробности в `man mktime`.

Comment: На здоровье.